# MSMQ/.NET - Peek message currently part of a transaction

Tags: .net, powershell, c#-4.0, msmq

I'm trying to create a small service application that will monitor a number of MSMQ's to time how long it's taking for the a separate listening application to process each message and take corrective action after a timeout period. I would like to retrieve the message that is currently part of a transaction using .NET (or powershell). However, all I've been able to come up with is retrieving the next un-read message in the queue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the messages of a message queue using MessageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2 method of the queue without dequeuing any message from the queue. Here is how it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getmessageenumerator2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: GetMessageEnumerator2 will only return the next message in the queue. I need to get a message that is currently in a transaction (in another application).
            MessageQueueTransaction myTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();

            MessageQueue myQueue1 = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\MyQueue");
            MessageQueue myQueue2 = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\MyQueue");

            myTransaction.Begin();

            Message myMessage = myQueue1.Receive(myTransaction);

            Message theSameMessage = myQueue2.Peek(); // <-- How to get same message?

            ...

Comment: So you want to look at a message that has already been received by a transaction that has not yet committed? The original message is flagged as invisible by MSMQ so you won't see it in the queue until the transaction aborts and makes it visible again. That's why enumeration won't work.

Comment: Not something I've ever seen someone do before. Can you use MSMQMessage.Id or MSMQMessage.LookupId?

Comment: You can't receive same message twice. What you can do is fire some kind of event on receiving a message and process that event for monitoring purpose. You can use simple .net event in case of same process, or signalr or a new msmq queue for the case of interprocess monitoring.

Comment: "You can't receive same message twice. " Of course, what was I thinking?